# Connection between php and scilab (FuzzyToolbox)

Tags: php, logic, scilab, fuzzy

I want to do connection between php and scilab, this my code

```
try {
  $path = 'C:\\wamp64\\apps\\scilab-5.5.2\\bin\\Scilex.exe';
  $path_script = "ea=loadfls('C:\\wamp64\\www\\scilab\\estilosaprendizaje.fls');res=evalfls([-11,11],ea); disp(res);exit;";
  $command = $path . '  -nb -e "' . $path_script.'"';
  echo $command;

  exec($command, $output);
  foreach ($output as $line) {
    print_r($line);
    echo "<br />";
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Excepción capturada: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

but when I run the php, it does not work, it keeps loading, I do not have error messages or anything.

In scilab my code it works.
[My output in scilab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFbz2.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What happens when you var_dump $path_script and then run the results from the command line? Do you get what you expect?

Comment: Hi, @MandyShaw, i have update my question, for add my output in scilab, only i want to show in my php de value of my var res, in this case is "30", thank you for answering me

Comment: Sorry, I meant $command not $path_script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `-nw` to `$command` to lauch scilab in console mode. It may be because scilab try to launch itself in graphical mode. I dont have php nor fuzzy toolbox, so I could not test it.